# Python os.path.walk() method

Tags: python

I'm currently using the `walk` method in a uni assignment. It's all working fine, but I was hoping that someone could explain something to me.

in the example below, what is the `a` parameter used for on the `myvisit` method?

```
>>> from os.path import walk
>>> def myvisit(a, dir, files):
...   print dir,": %d files"%len(files)

>>> walk('/etc', myvisit, None)
/etc : 193 files
/etc/default : 12 files
/etc/cron.d : 6 files
/etc/rc.d : 6 files
/etc/rc.d/rc0.d : 18 files
/etc/rc.d/rc1.d : 27 files
/etc/rc.d/rc2.d : 42 files
/etc/rc.d/rc3.d : 17 files
/etc/rc.d/rcS.d : 13 files
```

Comment: `os.path.walk` is deprecated, use `os.walk`

Comment: is that the same for `os.path.exists` and `os.path.isdir` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the argument you gave to walk, None in the example in your question

Comment: The usual way in Python to specify that an argument or variable is not of interest is to use the underscore ('_') character as the argument name. This is only a convention, but some IDEs (PyDev, for example) honors this when checking for unused variables.

Answer (score 29):

The first argument to your callback function is the last argument of the `os.path.walk` function. Its most obvious use is to allow you to keep state between the successive calls to the helper function (in your case, `myvisit`).

`os.path.walk` is a deprecated function. You really should use `os.walk`, which has no need for either a callback function or helper arguments (like `a` in your example).

```
for directory, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(some_path):
    # run here your code
```